# mysqldump can write to /tmp and /var/tmp but nowhere else

Tags: mysql, permissions, mysqldump

I have various MySQL databases on different servers and at different versions. I'm using the same `mysqldump` command across Linux versions without issue except for this new Red Hat 7.6 server.

Command:

```bash
mysqldump --tab=/var/tmp/mysql/mysql.20190808/wikidb \
--opt --user=root --password=[password] wikidb
```

Prior to the mysqldump command:

```bash
mkdir -p /var/tmp/mysql/mysql.20190808/wikidb
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/tmp/mysql/mysql.20190808
chmod 777 /var/tmp/mysql/mysql.20190808
```

This is all scripted so no chance for a typo.

On all the older servers, and especially the older wiki servers this server is replacing, the command works successfully. I get a list of all the tables and `.txt` files for the database in the directory.

On the new server, I get the very first table, `back_archive.sql`, and then an error:

> mysqldump: Got error: 1: "Can't create/write to file '/var/tmp/mysql/mysql.20190808/wikidb/back_archive.txt' (Errcode: 2)" when executing 'SELECT INTO OUTFILE'

I've tried various permissions including 1777 to give it a sticky bit just in case and it still fails. Ownership is confirmed as `mysql:mysql` and the database owner is `mysql`.

I'd done quite a bit of searching and reading of the man pages and everyone pretty much blames it on ownership or directory permissions but as noted above, I believe I've done it correctly, especially since it's a script and is working on every other server.

I will note this is my first master/master replication server. I didn't find anything specific regarding this sort of configuration but I thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the initial problem which was the txt files were being stored in a protected directory in `/var/tmp`.

The solution however was to store the files into a directory outside of the `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` directory structure. The powers that be decided that the output shouldn't be viewable to the non-mysql account so worked around it by putting into a hashed directory in `/var/tmp`.

I changed the output directory to `/opt/mysqlbackup` and haven't had a problem since.

Answer (score 0):

[Lots of] Other things can get in the way.

SELinux can cause all sorts of problems, making really *basic* things fail for no apparent [or announced] reason.

ACL's in the file system can cause confusion, sneakily "tweaking" permissions without you realising it.

Is it possible that the MySQL configuration is different?
These days, a clean install of MySQL might well come with [--secure-file-priv](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) turned on.  If that doesn't match where you're trying to put the file, you'll hit another wall.

Regards,   Phill  W.

Comment: I guess the main reply is that it writes one file, the .sql table, and then can't write any more files, the .txt data file. I manage the server so I know SELinux is disabled and we're not using ACLs. And I just verified that the --secure-file-priv option isn't enabled in my.cnf or any of the my.cnf.d files.

Comment: systemd defaults of `ProtectHome` and `ProtectSystem` also significantly restrict write locations.